# Stringbuilder TrimEnd() why is it not removing my char?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

Just a quick question.

I have a list
collection = David, Bob, Ted

```
foreach (var value in collection)
{
    sb.Append(value);
    sb.Append(",");
}
sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
```

**Output: David, Bob, Ted,**

However when I try to trim off "," for the last value

```
sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
```

It still appears when I run it. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: You need to write the trimmed string back into a variable. It doesn't modify the original string, it returns a new one after it was trimmed.

Comment: @TobiasTengler ah I see so i cant modify exisitng variable it has to be on a new variable to modify anything. Make sense thank you

Comment: Even though this solves your problem. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55966478/9456781) for a better way to join your collection with a `,`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable you are always creating a copy with a change and you are not using your new copy hens you do not see the change. To fix it use your copy of a string:

```
var result = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
```

or modify string builder itself before calling `ToString()`:

```
sb.Length--;
var result = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in my comment, you need to write the trimmed string back into a variable:

```
var output = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
```

But StringBuilder doesn't seem to be the right tool to seperate your collection items with a `,`.

[`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) seems like a much better fit for the task:

```
var output = string.Join(",", collection);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to print trimmed result, Try this;

```
foreach (var value in collection)
{
    sb.Append(value);
    sb.Append(",");
}
var result = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to remove the last N characters, in this case 1 :

```
var result = sb.ToString().Substring(0, sb.ToString().Length - 1);
```